# c#: How to resolve conflicts in config file?

Tags: .net, config

I am using two libraries that use the same value in app.config (appSettings/AppId) for different goals. I need to provide different values for them. I cannot change the libraries, because they are third party. Is there a way to resolve the conflict?

Comment: As far as I know, no, in general there is no easy way to resolve such a conflict. Two things I can think of: (1) Initialize the two libraries at different times, and in between, rewrite the .config file and reinitialize the configuration subsystem. (2) Split your application in two parts (i.e. two .exes) that each have their own .config file, then have these two parts communicate over pipes or network sockets or whatever. -- Both options are pretty terrible IMO.

Comment: why don't you just rename one of these?

Comment: Split the the project where app.config is common between the libraries into two projects with separate app.config let call those projects integration1 and integration2, reuse those in main project